# Match a value within a subset and return a value

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, match

I would like to return the ProjectID when certain criteria are met. For example, in the data below within each cluster where there is a project C and a project A the ProjectID for C will be returned in the row of project A. I have put an example below with the ProjectID being returned in the Dependent column. I have tried to solve the problem by using the group_by function within dplyr to separate each cluster into groups however I am unsure how to lookup the projects within each group to see if the criteria are met (in this case project C is within the cluster) and return the ProjectID. Would appreciate any advice on how to solve.

```
Cluster Project ProjectID Dependent
Aaa        A         1       3
Aaa        B         2
Aaa        C         3
Bbb        A         4
Bbb        B         5
Ccc        A         6       8
Ccc        B         7
Ccc        C         8
Ccc        D         9
```

Comment: Anis related to C what about B and D? Should you also output 1 under dependence where there is a C ?

Comment: Only required for project A if there is a project C within the cluster. B and D are not dependent on project C so do not need any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already few good answers have been provided but I think another way could be using `left_join` to `self` as:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1,filter(df1, Project=="C"),  by="Cluster") %>%
  mutate(Dependent = ifelse(Project.x == "A",  ProjectID.y, NA)) %>%
  select(Cluster, Project = Project.x, ProjectID = ProjectID.x, Dependent)
```

The `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
df1[Project == "A"][df1[Project == "C"], on="Cluster", nomatch=0][
df1, on=.(Cluster, Project)][
,.(Cluster, Project, ProjectID = i.ProjectID.1, Dependent = i.ProjectID)]


#       Cluster Project ProjectID Dependent
# 1     Aaa       A         1         3
# 2     Aaa       B         2        NA
# 3     Aaa       C         3        NA
# 4     Bbb       A         4        NA
# 5     Bbb       B         5        NA
# 6     Ccc       A         6         8
# 7     Ccc       B         7        NA
# 8     Ccc       C         8        NA
# 9     Ccc       D         9        NA
```

Hopefully, its worth considering performance of these approaches.

Answer (score 4):

I think this will provide the expected output:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Cluster) %>%
  mutate(Dependent = ifelse(Project == "A", ProjectID[Project=="C"], NA))
#output
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups: Cluster [3]
  Cluster Project ProjectID Dependent
  <fct>   <fct>       <int>     <int>
1 Aaa     A               1         3
2 Aaa     B               2        NA
3 Aaa     C               3        NA
4 Bbb     A               4        NA
5 Bbb     B               5        NA
6 Ccc     A               6         8
7 Ccc     B               7        NA
8 Ccc     C               8        NA
9 Ccc     D               9        NA
```

Within each cluster if project A return the projectID of project C else return NA

data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="Cluster Project ProjectID 
Aaa        A         1       
Aaa        B         2
Aaa        C         3
Bbb        A         4
Bbb        B         5
Ccc        A         6       
Ccc        B         7
Ccc        C         8
Ccc        D         9", header = TRUE)
```

bench-marking provided answers on small data set

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(missuse = df1 %>%
                 group_by(Cluster) %>%
                 mutate(Dependent = ifelse(Project == "A", ProjectID[Project=="C"], NA)),
               Rui_Barradas = lapply(split(df1, df1$Cluster), function(DF){
                 DF$Dependent <- NA
                 if(any(DF$Project == "A") && any(DF$Project == "C"))
                   DF$Dependent[DF$Project == "A"] <- DF$ProjectID[DF$Project == "C"]
                 DF
               }),
               MKR = left_join(df1,filter(df1, Project=="C"),  by="Cluster") %>%
                   mutate(Dependent = ifelse(Project.x == "A",  ProjectID.y, NA)) %>%
                   select(Cluster, Project = Project.x, ProjectID = ProjectID.x, Dependent)
               )

Unit: milliseconds
         expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
      missuse 3.525404 3.566450  4.220243  3.604535  3.785439 40.69046   100  b 
 Rui_Barradas 1.390526 1.423534  1.685952  1.495683  1.511552 16.30843   100 a  
          MKR 9.770077 9.959867 10.605632 10.215248 10.592078 21.14565   100   c
```

bench-mark on bigger data set  (90k rows)

```
df1 <- df1[rep(1:nrow(df1), times = 10000),]

microbenchmark(missuse = df1 %>%
                 group_by(Cluster) %>%
                 mutate(Dependent = ifelse(Project == "A", ProjectID[Project=="C"], NA)),
               Rui_Barradas = lapply(split(df1, df1$Cluster), function(DF){
                 DF$Dependent <- NA
                 if(any(DF$Project == "A") && any(DF$Project == "C"))
                   DF$Dependent[DF$Project == "A"] <- DF$ProjectID[DF$Project == "C"]
                 DF
               }), times = 20)

Unit: milliseconds
         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
      missuse 25.05783 25.53072 29.95501 25.83243 28.49352 55.34345    20  a 
 Rui_Barradas 35.42203 36.85572 47.61315 39.87882 56.25432 95.80752    20   b
```

and on 900k rows:

```
df1 <- df1[rep(1:nrow(df1), times = 100000),] #original df1

Unit: milliseconds
         expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
      missuse 466.6968 721.9709  945.8628 1062.6262 1101.914 1255.214    20   a
 Rui_Barradas 718.8869 768.0912 1077.7594  934.1785 1308.145 1854.415    20   a
```

I left out MKR answer in the last two bench marks because it was crashing my session.

Disclaimer: I run the bench-marks on a potato PC. I will retest on another, more up to  date PC, later and if the results are different (in terms of relative performance) I will update the answer.

UPDATE: I feel the generated data (by me) is a bit deceptive. Here is another attempt:

```
df1 <- df1[rep(1:nrow(df1), times = 10000),]

df1 %>%
  mutate(rle = rleid(Cluster)) %>%
  mutate(Cluster = paste(Cluster, rle, sep = "_")) %>%
  select(-rle) -> df1

MKR2 <- function(df1){
setDT(df1)
df1[Project == "A"][df1[Project == "C"], on="Cluster", nomatch=0][
  df1, on=.(Cluster, Project)][
    ,.(Cluster, Project, ProjectID = i.ProjectID.1, Dependent = i.ProjectID)]
}
```

so data with lots of small groups

Here I had to leave out  Rui Barradas solution because it was taking too long:

```
microbenchmark(missuse = df1 %>%
                 group_by(Cluster) %>%
                 mutate(Dependent = ifelse(Project == "A", ProjectID[Project=="C"], NA)),
               MKR = left_join(df1,filter(df1, Project=="C"),  by="Cluster") %>%
                   mutate(Dependent = ifelse(Project.x == "A",  ProjectID.y, NA)) %>%
                   select(Cluster, Project = Project.x, ProjectID = ProjectID.x, Dependent),
               MKR2(df1),
               times = 10
               )

Unit: milliseconds
      expr        min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval cld
   missuse 7445.97748 7815.2364 9609.4009 8350.0508 9565.2411 19965.5040    10   b
       MKR   55.61109   59.9900  123.2263   80.4056  191.7361   250.5065    10  a 
 MKR2(df1)  100.97692  216.4811  994.8457  277.3159 1452.0668  4011.1804    10  a
```

Interesting stuff

Comment: Thank mate. Clearly self-join hasn't helped in this case. I think join could have been a little smarter.

Comment: I know. self-joins are faster only in `data.table`. I need to rework my answer.

Comment: Only the last `select` part is taking `50%` of total time.

Comment: That's what was surprising me. What is MKR2? Is that `data.table`?

Comment: Ahh okay. Perhaps (`setDT`) has slowed it down otherwise it should have been faster. Thanks for all your effort mate. It gave interesting results.

Answer (score 3):

With base R only you can do the following.

```
sp <- lapply(split(dat, dat$Cluster), function(DF){
    DF$Dependent <- NA
    if(any(DF$Project == "A") && any(DF$Project == "C"))
        DF$Dependent[DF$Project == "A"] <- DF$ProjectID[DF$Project == "C"]
    DF
})

result <- do.call(rbind, sp)
row.names(result) <- NULL
result
#  Cluster Project ProjectID Dependent
#1     Aaa       A         1         3
#2     Aaa       B         2        NA
#3     Aaa       C         3        NA
#4     Bbb       A         4        NA
#5     Bbb       B         5        NA
#6     Ccc       A         6         8
#7     Ccc       B         7        NA
#8     Ccc       C         8        NA
#9     Ccc       D         9        NA
```

**DATA.**

```
dat <-
structure(list(Cluster = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Aaa", "Bbb", "Ccc"), class = "factor"), 
    Project = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), ProjectID = 1:9), .Names = c("Cluster", 
"Project", "ProjectID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 1):

data.table way of solving this

```
df1[Project == 'A'][df1[Project == 'C'], 
Dependent := i.ProjectID, 
on = 'Cluster'][df1, on =
c('Cluster', 'Project', 'ProjectID')]
```

subset df1 where `project=='A'`,

then right join subset of df1 where `Project =='C'`, on `'Cluster'`

then right join itself again, on cluster, project, and project ID.

I'm not sure if this would run on large datasets, since it has a lot of self-joins, especially when data is repetitive, since data table wouldn't let you join if you have duplicated key-values.

```
   Cluster Project ProjectID Dependent
1:     Aaa       A         1         3
2:     Aaa       B         2        NA
3:     Aaa       C         3        NA
4:     Bbb       A         4        NA
5:     Bbb       B         5        NA
6:     Ccc       A         6         8
7:     Ccc       B         7        NA
8:     Ccc       C         8        NA
9:     Ccc       D         9        NA
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` way, seems to be a bit faster than @missuse's way :

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(Cluster) %>%
  mutate(Dependent= `[<-`(rep_len(NA_integer_,n()),
                          Project=="A",
                          value=ProjectID[match("C",Project)]))

# # A tibble: 9 x 4
# # Groups:   Cluster [3]
# Cluster Project ProjectID Dependent
# <fctr>  <fctr>     <int>     <int>
# 1     Aaa       A         1         3
# 2     Aaa       B         2        NA
# 3     Aaa       C         3        NA
# 4     Bbb       A         4        NA
# 5     Bbb       B         5        NA
# 6     Ccc       A         6         8
# 7     Ccc       B         7        NA
# 8     Ccc       C         8        NA
# 9     Ccc       D         9        NA
```